# Python numpy.convolve integral limits

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, convolution

I have a convolution integral that has a similar form described in this post: ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965040/python-numpy-convolve-to-solve-convolution-integral-with-limits-from-0-to-t-inst))

Instead of integrating from 0 to t, I need to integrate from minus infinity to t. I was not able to do this, however, using `numpy.convolve`, as it always return results from minus infinity to plus infinity.
Using `scipy.integrate.quad` would be very slow as I have to loop through every `t`, and it only works for integrands that have analytical expressions.

Is there a way to specify the lower and upper limits of `numpy.convolve`? Thank you very much.

Here is the code (I apologize for not be able to type LaTeX equation here):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate

def gaussian(tau, mu, sigma):

    pdf = 1/(sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) * np.exp( - (tau - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))
    return pdf

def gaussian_deriv(tau, mu, sigma):
    """
    derivative of gaussian function
    """
    pdf = -(tau - mu)/sigma**2 * gaussian(tau, mu, sigma)
    return pdf

def integral_kernel(tau):
    return np.cbrt(1/tau)

def integrand(tau, t, mu, sigma):

    return gaussian_deriv(tau, mu, sigma) * integral_kernel(t - tau + 1E-28)

tau = np.linspace(-7, 7, 1000)
dtau = tau[1] - tau[0]
lower_lim = tau[0]
g_deriv = gaussian_deriv(tau, mu=0, sigma=1)

result = np.zeros_like(tau)
for idx, t in np.ndenumerate(tau):
    result[idx], err = integrate.quad(integrand, lower_lim, t, args=(t, mu, sigma), points=[t])

result_convolve = np.convolve(g_deriv, integral_kernel(tau), mode='same') * dtau

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(10, 6))
ax[0].plot(tau, result, 'r-', label='scipy quad')
ax[1].plot(tau, result_convolve, '.', label='numpy convolve')
ax[0].legend()
ax[1].legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want the integral

int{-inf...T}  f(tau) g(t-tau) dtau

Writing H(t) = 1/2 (sign(t) + 1) this is the same as

int{-inf...inf}  f(tau) g(t-tau) [1 - H(tau-T)] dtau

or

int{-inf...inf}  f^(tau) g(t-tau) dtau = f^*g(t)

with f^(tau) = f(tau) * [1 - H(tau-T)].

So all you need to do is to zero out f right of T to get f^ and then compute the conventional convolution f^*g.

**Update**

If t and T are the same number it's even slightly simpler:

int{-inf...t} f(tau)g(t-tau) dtau

In this case you can shift the integration variable by t, so you get:

int{-inf...0} f(tau+t}g(-tau) dtau

next you replace tau with -tau

int{0...inf} g(tau) f(t-tau) dtau

and now you proceed more or less as above only T is now fixed and equal to zero and you don't zero out right of T but left of T.

Comment: How to zero out f(tau) when tau > T ? I tried step function `numpy.piecewise` such that f =0 if tau > 0, but it did not work. Instead, I obtained something very close to actual result, but slightly deviate from it.

Comment: You could do something like: `def cut(tau, f, T):` `out=np.zeros(np.shape(tau))` `tau = np.asanyarray(tau)` `mask = tau <= T` `out[mask] = f(tau[mask])` `return out`

Comment: I am a bit confused. The function `numpy.convolve` returns result as a function of T ( array with the same size as T). If I proceed with what you suggested above, I would have to loop through every elements of T and evaluate the integral, isn't it ? If it's possible, I would like to stick with using `numpy.convolve`.

Comment: @misterdone What I've written assumes `T` fixed scalar, `tau` integration variable, `t` convolution offsets (a vector) once you have computed f^, which amounts to calling `cut(t, f, T)` once on a grid `t` you call `convolve` also once on the result and `g` and  that's it

Comment: @misterdone If you mean't t=T the result is different but similar, I've updated the post to cover this case, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it works. I also found that the region of integration must be symmetric with respect to t=0, else the result of `numpy.convolve` will be shifted left or right. Is there a way to shift it back ?

Comment: @misterdone `convolve` will use all the data you give it. So at mode "full" the result will range between t0 + s0 and t1 + s1 if  your inputs range between t0 and t1 and s0 and s1. At "same" assuming t1 - t0 is larger than s1 - s0 it will be t0 + (s0 + s1) / 2 and t1 + (s0 + s1) / 2 and at "valid" it will be t0 + s1 and t1 + s0. If both your inputs contain 0 you can make diagnostic inputs using `np.zeros` and placing a 1 at the offset corresponding to 0. Convolve those and find the the 1 in the output. Its position corresponds to 0.

Comment: Hi, It does not work for the case above. Nevertheless, thank you very much for your help. I gain better understanding on `numpy.convolve`.

Answer (score 0):

Again this is a rather old post, still I am presenting my analysis here.

Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69366412/1519715) where I have answered the question cited by OP. It is necessary to go through this post to under the notations and symbols used here.

What `np.convolve(A, B)` gives you is

[image]

and what you are looking for is

[image]

Here the second term will be zero as `B` for negative coefficients is extrapolated to zero.
So you see you don't have to do anything as

[image].